# Bellman-Ford algorithm's intermediate optimality property, is it correct?

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, shortest-path

Bellman-Ford algorithm is famously known to solve the *single source shortest path problem* (SSSPP) for any arbitrary connected graph *G(V,E)* with additive edge weights, whenever one exists.

The basic implementation version of the algorithm for e.g.: [Bellman-Ford-Wiki-page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm#Algorithm) and its [proof of correctness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm#Proof_of_correctness), when used **parallel relaxation** of all edges, as per my understanding, implies an interesting by-product, which I call as "intermediate optimality property", (which might be very helpful for some applications like [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/29772/21559)) is stated as below:

> After *k* iterations, we have *every* node identified with its shortest path from the same source, under the constraint of #edges in the path is <= *k*

This, under the assumption of simple shortest-path existence, will ensure producing the shortest path solution to SSSPP, for *every* destination node, after *at most* *|V|-1* iterations.

**Is the above property correct?**

According to some people (for e.g. comments just below [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/29772/21559)), it is not correct and I fail to understand why!!

(UPDATED: I am using a parallel update on all the vertices.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose we have a simple graph A->B->C->D with all weights equal to 1.

If we visit the vertices in the order A,B,C,D then during the first iteration we will relax all of the following:

```
A->B, finds shortest path to B is 1
B->C, finds shortest path to C is 2
C->D, finds shortest path to D is 3.
```

So in the first iteration we have found the shortest path to D despite this path needing 3 edges.

However, if the vertices were visited in the order D,C,B,A it would take more iterations to find the shortest path to D.

In other words, after k iterations we will have certainly found any shortest paths with #edges <= k, however we may also have found a better route that uses more edges.

Comment: Thats perfect. I want to use parallel update to all vertices. Is it correct then?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realise you were using parallel update.  In that case I think your property does become correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quickest clarification.  I have been struggling  to confirm this for a long time today..